# Does Slack uses each server instance for each work space or organization?

Tags: slack, rocket.chat

I am trying to setup https://rocket.chat/ in my existing web app.

RocketChat allows only one organization per instance(Server + Database).
Ref link: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/658

I was wondering does "Slack" also uses the same scenario as above.

Since earlier "Slack" uses sub-domain for each organization that might be due to "each instance for each organization" scenario.

Comment: Why would it matter from a developer or user perspective? Just curious!

Comment: @SenG If my thought is wrong and slack can allow multiple organization in one instance.Then it will help me to dig more on RocketChat code to tweak it. If not then it will be a waste of time digging their code.